# A property of centers of circumcircle, incircle and nine point circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

About 2 hours ago I came up with a very cool feature of Euclidean geometry, but it's much more difficult than I can handle, any help would be appreciated.

If we draw the circumcircle, the incircle and the nine point circle, then the circle passing through the centers of these three circles is congruent with the nine point circle if and only if it is tangent to the circumcircle.

Is this property already known?

[image]

If the answer is yes, please include references that you can remember.

How do we prove that anyway?

Comment: In case anyone wants, I've drawn a movable graph of this problem. You may move the three vertices of the triangle to see different situations. https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/qxdmggz5

Comment: What convince you this is true though? It looks true but it is too complicated so I am not sure.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to simplify your title and your text by using the appropriate names for these circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually known and follows from the statements:

1. The radius of a triangle's circumcircle is twice the radius of that triangle's nine-point circle ([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle#Other_properties_of_the_nine-point_circle)).
2. If a circle passes through the center of a circumcircle and tangents to it, then its radius is twice the radius of the circumcircle.

Comment: I actually proved this a little while ago, but the internet was down and I couldn't put it as an answer. Indeed, the matter is not related to the center of the circle tangent to the triangle, but rather to the similarity of the two circles.

Comment: @زكريا حسناو, You have come up with an excellent question, congratulations. The rest of it is irrelevant.